# Understanding dispatch_queues and synchronous/asynchronous dispatch

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios-multithreading

I'm an Android engineer trying to port some iOS code that uses 5 SERIAL dispatch queues.  I want to make sure I'm thinking about things the right way.

- dispatch_sync to a SERIAL queue is basically using the queue as a synchronized queue-  only one thread may access it and the block that gets executed can be thought of as a critical region.  It happens immediately on the current thread-  its the equivalent of

  ```
  get_semaphore()
  queue.pop()
  do_block()
  release_semaphore()
  ```
- dispatch_async to a serial queue-  performs the block on another thread and lets the current thread return immediately.  However since its a serial queue it promises only one of these asynchronous thread is going to execute at a time (the next call to dispatch_async will wait until all other threads are finished).  That block can also be thought of as a critical region, but it will occur on another thread.  So the same code as above, but its passed to a worker thread first.

Am I off in any of that, or did I figure it out correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like an overly complicated way of thinking of it and there are lots of little details of that description that aren't quite right. Specifically, "it happens immediately on the current thread" is not correct.

First, let's step back: The distinction between `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` is merely whether the current thread waits for it or not. But when you dispatch something to a serial queue, you should always imagine that it's running on a separate worker thread of GCD's own choosing. Yes, as an optimization, sometimes `dispatch_sync` will use the current thread, but you are in no way guaranteed of this fact.

Second, when you discuss `dispatch_sync`, you say something about it running "immediately". But it's by no means assured to be immediate. If a thread does `dispatch_sync` to some serial queue, then that thread will block until (a) any block currently running on on that serial queue finish; (b) any other queued blocks for that serial queue run and complete; and (c) obviously, the block that thread A itself dispatched runs and completes.

Now, when you use a serial queue for synchronization for, some thread-safe access to some object in memory, often that synchronization process is very quick, so the waiting thread will generally be blocked for a negligible amount of time as its dispatched block (and any prior dispatched blocks) to finish. But in general, it's misleading to say that it will run immediately. (If it always could run immediately, then you wouldn't need a queue to synchronize access).

---

Now your question talks about a "critical region", to which I assume you're talking about some bit of code that, in order to ensure thread-safety or for some other reason like that, must be synchronized. So, when running this code to be synchronized, the only question re `dispatch_sync` vs `dispatch_async` is whether the current thread must wait. A common pattern, for example, is to say that one may `dispatch_async` writes to some model (because there's no need to wait for the model to update before proceeding), but `dispatch_sync` reads from some model (because you obviously don't want to proceed until the read value is returned).

A further optimization of that sync/async pattern is the reader-writer pattern, where concurrent reads are permissible but concurrent writes are not. Thus, you'll use a concurrent queue, `dispatch_barrier_async` the writes (achieving serial-like behavior for the writes), but `dispatch_sync` the reads (enjoying concurrent performance with respect to other read operations).

Comment: Critical region is another name for critical section:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you meant. In iOS we refer to that as needing to be "synchronized". See [Threading Programming Guide: Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1). But that predates GCD, which is discussed in [Concurrency Programming Guide: Eliminating Lock-Based Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3).

Comment: Yeah.  So I was a little sloppy with terming things immediate, but I had what it was doing right.  Luckily I think I can simplify down to 1 message queue for the Android implementation, not having an architecture built around core data notifications makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

To pick nits, dispatch_sync doesn't necessarily run the code on the current thread, but if it doesn't, it still blocks the current thread until the task completes.  The distinction is only potentially important if you're relying on thread IDs or thread-local storage.

But otherwise, yes, unless I missed something subtle.

Comment: Good to know.  Revised answer.